# USB mouse/ trackpad not letting gestures. Content Caching, Touch Display

Tags: iphone, macbook-pro, display, hardware

I have in Sharing on My MacBook Pro... Content Caching - Share internet connection. Share this computer internet connection and cached content with iOS devices using USB.

I see on my iPhone under Touch Display - Unlock iPhone to allow USB accessories connect when it has been more than an hour since your iPhone was locked.

My trackpad stopped working a while back and now I have this Logitech that I found around in the house. I have seen on here that Logitech can be used for several computer monitors. So is it possible that I can go on a different computer with my USB mouse and access my MacBook Pro?

Comment: Why can't you just connect the Logitech mouse to your MacBook directly?

Comment: It is directly connected, because my settings are forcing me to keep it connected if I want to use my computer. That is why I question.